# how to remove certain field from datatable using jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

Hi I am using datatables. My requirment is to remove certain fields from search parameters

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example thead tr')
        .clone(true)
        .addClass('filters')
        .appendTo('#example thead tr');

    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        orderCellsTop: true,
        fixedHeader: true,
        initComplete: function () {
            var api = this.api();

            // For each column
            api
                .columns()
                .eq(0)
                .each(function (colIdx) {
                    // Set the header cell to contain the input element
                    var cell = $('.filters th').eq(
                        $(api.column(colIdx).header()).index()
                    );
                    var title = $(cell).text();
                    $(cell).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" />');

                    // On every keypress in this input
                    $(
                        'input',
                        $('.filters th').eq($(api.column(colIdx).header()).index())
                    )
                        .off('keyup change')
                        .on('keyup change', function (e) {
                            e.stopPropagation();

                            // Get the search value
                            $(this).attr('title', $(this).val());
                            var regexr = '({search})'; //$(this).parents('th').find('select').val();

                            var cursorPosition = this.selectionStart;
                            // Search the column for that value
                            api
                                .column(colIdx)
                                .search(
                                    this.value != ''
                                        ? regexr.replace('{search}', '(((' + this.value + ')))')
                                        : '',
                                    this.value != '',
                                    this.value == ''
                                )
                                .draw();

                            $(this)
                                .focus()[0]
                                .setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
                        });
                });
        },
    });

});
```

Here is my code of table on which I'm applying the datattables

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:10px;">
        <thead class="thead">
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Employee</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Arrival time </th>
                <th>Departure Time

                </th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($attandance as $attandances)
            <tr>

                <td class="{{ ( $attandances->total_hours < 9 ) ? 'danger' : 'success' }}">{{$attandances->code}}</td>
                <td class="{{ ( $attandances->total_hours < 9 ) ? 'danger' : 'success' }}">{{$attandances->employee}}</td>
                <td class="{{ ( $attandances->total_hours < 9 ) ? 'danger' : 'success' }}">{{$attandances->date}}</td>
                <td class="{{ ( $attandances->total_hours < 9 ) ? 'danger' : 'success' }}">{{$attandances->start_time}}</td>
                <td class="{{ ( $attandances->total_hours < 9 ) ? 'danger' : 'success' }}"> {{$attandances->end_time}}</td>
                <td class="{{ ( $attandances->total_hours < 9 ) ? 'danger' : 'success' }}">{{$attandances->total_hours}}</td>

            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>


    </table>
```

Currently it is showing all the headers of table as a search fields I want to remove fields such as `arrival time` and `departure time` from the datatable search function how I can achieve this?

Comment: What does server side code look like? How are you retrieving the data?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columns": [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    { "searchable": false },
    { "searchable": false },
    null
  ] } );
} );
```

Check the documentation:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.searchable